# FUSE - avoid calculating size in GetAttr

Tags: go, fuse

I'm implementing a FUSE file system for a remote service.
When the user opens a file I do a network call to get the file's contents. [It appears](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/issues/186) that the file's size must be reported through `GetAttr` in order for open to work.
In order to know the file's size, I have to issue a network call, and since `GetAttr` is called for every entry when doing `ls`, I'm concerned about this design (if a user does `ls` in a directory with many items, it will have to get all the files, even if the user didn't want to open any of them).

How can I work around this problem? My thoughts were:

- Use a lower level method for reading that doesn't rely on reported size? I thought using `Read` instead of `Open` could help, however I couldn't get it to work without a size.
- If I could distinguish `GetAttr` calls that originated from `Open` from other calls (including `ls`), I could issue the network calls only when needed.

I use Go and [go-fuse](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse), but I think it shouldn't matter because it's a general FUSE question.

Also, FUSE docs are very minimal (missing actually) documentation. It would be nice if someone familiar with the matter can explain the call flow for `ls`, `cd` and `cat` - what FUSE functions are called in which order.
For example, why there is both `Open` and `Read`.

**Update:**
I've been browsing SSHFS which is considered the canonical example for a FUSE filesystem, and it seems that it also gets the file over network on getattr: https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/blob/master/sshfs.c#L3167
What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is because the the kernel is buffering your read, and when it does so, it uses the size of the inode to calculate exactly how many bytes it has to copy to userspace (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.7/source/mm/filemap.c#L2137). So there are different workarounds:

1. Return huge st_size from GetAttr
2. When you open the file, set the direct_io flag so you don't use page caches.

Comment: Setting the file size to something huge confuses some programs so that they attempt to allocate memory for the huge size and fail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the go-fuse's API. Below info is based on libfuse's API.

The SSHFS's GetAttr is implement in function `sshfs_getattr`, it looks like send network request get file size info.

When you run `cd`, it will run `.access` callback to check directory exists.

When you run `ls`, it will first call `.readdir` callback get dir info, then call `.getattr` get info for files in that dir.

When you run `cat`, it will first call `.getattr` get info for file and info for path. Then call `.open` => `.read` => `.release`.

FUSE's is lack of doc, you better first write an example, then you can add some `printf` in those callbacks to get some info.

1. In `.open`, you can create an privite data and set it to `fuse_file_info::fh`. This `fuse_file_info::fh` can be used in later `.read` callbacks.
2. You can set all size info to zero in `.getattr` callbacks. Then in `.open`, you set `fuse_file_info::direct_io` to 1. In `.read`, first read data from network, if you reach the end of file, then `return 0` in `.read`.

This [doc](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs135.201001/homework/fuse/fuse_doc.html) helps me a lot, when I wrote my filesystem.

Comment: Setting the file size to zero confuses some programs so that they don't even try to read the file.